# PHP variable inside HTML form does not get resolved to its value

Tags: php, html

I want to pass a value into an HTML form from a PHP script

```
echo '<form> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id" /></form>'
```

But this line passes `$id` as a literal string, but its value says "9".

How to pass its value?

Comment: `<form><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /></form>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<form> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'" /></form>'
```

Comment: you can not write <?php ?> within echo statement.

Comment: html elements and tags are string in php file.

Comment: exactly it works but 
value=" '.$id.' " 
can you clarify this

Comment: $id is variable of php that holds value =9 as you say. And other html elements and tags are as string.

Comment: ya but why we put single quote and dot inside double quote

Comment: this is concatenation process for string and php variable.

Comment: i am accepting your answer but if u clarify this concatenation process it would clear my understanding ...thanks a lot

Comment: in php for combination of sting and php variable we use dot sign to combine both.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include PHP tags. Try `<?php echo $id ?>`

Answer (score 0):

In `PHP` you can print out variables with `echo`:

```
<?php //This tells the page that the following is PHP

    echo "Hello, world!"; //outputs "Hello, world!"

    $id = 9;
    echo "The ID is: ".$id; //outputs "The ID is: 9"

    //Close the PHP code:
?>
```

So, to output a `PHP` variable inside of `HTML`, you write:

```
<form><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /></form>
```

Comment: no it prints everything inside double quote.
<input type="hidden" name="id "value="' . $id . '" /> this code works . but i dont understand this line

Answer (score 0):

Output PHP variable inside the HTML, should be done like :

```
<form><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /></form>
```

**EDIT :**

*Since the question has been edited after I posted my answer*, so you can also use both the ways, the above code that I've mentioned and also you use this one :

```
echo '<form> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'" /></form>';
```

Comment: not working...it prints everything what inside double code as string

Comment: @JummoJuaHill, if you are passing HTML tag in php then you need to use `echo '<form> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'" /></form>'` where we have *concatenated* `$id` variable. Else you can use the other way as in the answer if you don't want to pass HTML tags in php

Comment: thank you so much bro but why single quote is needed inside double quote

Comment: Because in php this is how concatenation  is managed. It treats as a string `echo '<form> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'" /></form>'`

Comment: i appreciate your patience and thanks a lot for your help.. its very much clear to me now .god bless bro

Comment: @JummoJuaHill, I just hope that my answer and explanation solved your issue, as you edited the question after I posted my answer. So, I answered according to your question as well

Comment: ya bro i was missing the easiest concept because i couldnt match the single quotes. i was too much confused.you both tried lot but i understand about the matching single quotes seeing your answer though he answered lot ago.. i wish i could accept two answers. but now accepting your answer will be injustice for him too... :(

Comment: @JummoJuaHill, you can atleast upvote all the answers that helped to solve your issue. So, it can solve issue for others as well

Answer (score -1):

or just use

```
    $val=<<<AAA


     <form> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id" /></form>

AAA;
echo $val;
```

Copy as it is